# Trying to embed struct2 in struct1 where struct2 refers back to struct1 data

Tags: rust

`Struct1` uses an instance of `Struct2` to do stuff. Struct2 needs access to data inside its caller (struct1 here)

I cannot work out how to do it.

`Struct1` is already lifetimed - (ratatui Block, just included to force lifetime need since thats what the real code has). It has a `Vec<String>`, struct2 needs access to it (not a copy) in order to do its work.

I would prefer to have that binding done in the `Struct1::new` function but could not work out how to do that. So I made a separate function, that the users of struct1 have to call (not very transparent). But even if I do that I get borrowing complaints when using Struct1

Note: The `refcell` is there because struct2 methods needs to be called mutably even in an immutable context (in the real code)

This code compiles and runs

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

use ratatui::widgets::block::Block;

struct Struct1<'a> {
    field1: i32,
    lines: Vec<String>,
    field2: i32,
    bl: Option<Block<'a>>,
    s2: RefCell<Struct2<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Struct1<'a> {
    fn new(lines: Vec<String>) -> Self {
        let s = Self {
            field1: 0,
            field2: 0,
            bl: None,
            lines: lines,
            s2: RefCell::new(Struct2::new()),
        };

        s
    }
    fn f1(&mut self) {
        self.field1 = 1;
    }
    fn f2(&mut self) {
        self.field2 = 2;
    }
}

struct Struct2<'a> {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
     lines: Option<&'a Vec<String>>,
}

impl<'a> Struct2<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            field1: 0,
            field2: 0,
             lines: None,
        }
    }
    fn set_lines(&mut self, lines: &'a Vec<String>) {
        self.lines = Some(lines);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let l = vec!["hello world".to_string(), "hello world".to_string()];
    let mut s = Struct1::new(l);
    s.s2.borrow_mut().set_lines(&s.lines);
    println!("Hello, world!");
    //s.f1();
    //s.f2();
}
```

But as you see it doesnt do anything with `s`. If I uncomment the last 2 lines I get

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:56:5
   |
54 |     s.s2.borrow_mut().set_lines(&s.lines);
   |                                 -------- immutable borrow occurs here
55 |     println!("Hello, world!");
56 |     s.f1();
   |     ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
57 |     s.f2();
   |     - immutable borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:57:5
   |
54 |     s.s2.borrow_mut().set_lines(&s.lines);
   |                                 -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
57 |     s.f2();
   |     ^^--^^
   |     | |
   |     | immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

I am stuck. All the real code worked fine until I added that &Vec referring back to the parent struct. So I created this minimal repro.